# Executing the VBA code on opening the excel instead of Changing value

Tags: excel, ms-access, exception, vba

I have a VBA code for a Rota Sheet that is activated on change of any value in the row.

I want the code to be activated upon opening the excel.

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("B2:V11")

If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then

    'scan each row (month)
    Dim countRow As Long

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.count
        If Not Intersect(Target, rng.Rows(i)) Is Nothing Then
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng.Rows(i), "V") > 0 Then
                countRow = 0

                Dim cel As Range
                For Each cel In rng.Rows(i).Cells
                    If cel.Value2 = "V" Then
                        countRow = countRow + 1
                        VacationChange cel, countRow
                    Else
                        VacationChange cel, 0
                    End If
                Next cel
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    'scan each column (day)
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.count
        If Not Intersect(Target, rng.Columns(j)) Is Nothing Then
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng.Columns(j), "V") > 5 Then
                VacationChange rng.Columns(j).Cells(0, 1), 6
            Else
                VacationChange rng.Columns(j).Cells(0, 1), 0
            End If
        End If
    Next j

End If
End Sub

Private Function VacationChange(ByVal rng As Range, ByVal count As Long)

With rng.Interior
    Select Case count
        Case 0
            'clear cell colors
            .Pattern = xlNone
            .Color = xlNone
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        Case 1 To 3
            'blue
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .Color = 15773696
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        Case 4 To 5
            'yellow
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
            .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        Case Else
            'red
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .Color = 255
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End Select
End With

End Function
```

I spent efforts by trying:
1. Using below code in Workbook: which is throwing 424 error

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Sheet1.Activate
Call Worksheet_Change(Target)
End Sub
```

2. Pasting the entire code under Workbook_Open() function which is not working

Can anyone suggest what i am missing in the code ?

Sample Output image is attached
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwggX.png)

Comment: What is your goal when you **Open** the workbook? What do you expect to happen other than it activating `Sheet1`?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs : Initially I made the sheet considering that we will manually enter the details in the sheet, but now we do not have to manually enter the details. It is taking reference from other sheet and posting those values here. Meaning that there is no change of values in this sheet. Since there is no change of values, the Worksheet_Change command is not being called.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs: When we will open the workbook, the color coding will automatically happen. Just like shown in the image. All the color codes will be adjusted based on the count.

Comment: You need to declare the new range. Is the range always `("B2:V11")`?

Comment: @urdearboy: The range will always be constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Target is an undeclared `Variant` in your `Workbook_Open` implementation. That means when it gets passed as a parameter that needs to be a `Range`, the implicit cast fails and results in an error 424 (Object required).

If you want to "simulate" every cell in your target range changing, you can simply loop over `B2:V11` and pass it each individual cell (untested with your data, but should give the gist):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheet1.Activate
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("B2:V11")
        'Worksheet_Change needs to be Public
        Sheet1.Worksheet_Change cell
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that this is by no means the ideal solution to what you are trying to do and is a sign that you need to refactor your code a little bit to extract the functionality that you currently have in `Worksheet_Change` into a free-standing procedure.  If you need to run the same code from the `Worksheet_Change` handler, you can call that procedure.

Comment: Thank you So much for your efforts. The code does work!! 
But it is making the excel loading process very slow. 
Can there be better solution ?
Sorry, the question might be stupid as i am not from a technical background.
Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @AnkitDalal I'm not surprised that it slows it down a bit on open - you're running your change code on 210 individual cells. I'm guessing that the redraws are a pretty big performance hit - you could try turning off screen updating before you hit the loop.

Comment: That should be fine. I am happy that it worked without much alterations on the existing code.
Again thanks for the instant and correct response..